# Query to find IP address [old] from mysql table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ip

Created a Wordpress website on EC2 with Mysql [RDS] as the database.
The IP address got changed after a reboot and the website is not coming up.
Need to update the new IP in the Mysql database. 
Got the command to replace the old IP with the new one.

The command is as follows -

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = "http://"New.IP" WHERE option_value = 'old ip';
```

I wanted to know how to retrieve the old IP and how to query for the same in `WP_options` .

Tried

```
SELECT * FROM [mydatabase] WHERE wp_options LIKE 'option_value';
```

I didn't have any luck with that.

Comment: SELECT * FROM [mydatabase] WHERE option_value LIKE '%OLD_IP%';

Comment: My apologies, I need little more clarity on your response. What should I fill in the place of  "%OLD_IP% ". I don't know the old Ip value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using RDS, you should not be storing the IP address anywhere. Instead you should be using the DNS endpoint. The IP address for RDS will change over time.